# Re-order my records and then create(or reset if its possible) a new auto increment field in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to do something in MySQL, but I can't. I want to reorder 
my records in my table and then create(or reset if its possible) a new auto 
increment field in MySQL, as it is shown in the picture. I want to order them by middle column and then reset the first column.

[image]

Comment: Why are you reordering them in the DB when you can just order them any way you want when you retrieve them?

Comment: because i use that auto increament field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you start backup your table or database. After that you can create same table and set auto increment to the field which you want to be ai, somethign like this below:

```
CREATE TABLE sampleTable
(`ID` int auto_increment primary key, `Field1` int, `Field2` int);
```

**ID** will be your auto increment(in this example) and fields will be your fields(or you can just copy the structure of your table instead of writing them down again.)

Afterwards select your old table data by the order you want and insert into new table:

```
INSERT INTO sampleTable (`Field1`, `Field2`)
SELECT Field1, Field2
FROM oldTable
ORDER BY Field1;
```

So your new table will be sorted by the field you want and have their auto increment reset as well.